# Is it OK and possible to access properties from another Entity in EventListener (Symfony 4.4)?

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to EventListeners (even though I can read here and there that it is best to use subscribers) and I got maybe a silly question:
Can I access data from another table (Table 2) in my EventListener plugged in my Entity 1 (Table1).

Here my example:

representation of my table
[image: representation of my table]

I have an EventListener on my table 1 and want to access the rows E "crit2" and "crit3" to check their value.
If crit 2 is "combo", I would concatenate on F the value of A and D (Table 1) otherwise, the other, A and D.

I tried a eventListener and get a file NewOrganised.php in the folder EventListener:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;
use App\Entity\ProductsInfoOrganised;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
 
class NewOrganised
{
    // the listener methods receive an argument which gives you access to
    // both the entity object of the event and the entity manager itself
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
 
        // if this listener only applies to certain entity types,
        // add some code to check the entity type as early as possible
        if (!$entity instanceof ProductsInfoOrganised) {
            return;
        }
 
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
        // ... do something with the Product entity
    }
}
```

In my entity ProductsInfoOrganised aka Table 1, I added to the end

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
*/
public function setValuesLeftBlank(): void
{
     $this->triabc = $this->packId . $this->adapteGaucher;
     $this->triacb = $this->adapteGaucher . $this->packId;
//   if( $crit2 == "localisation" ) {
//   $this->triId = $this->shopId . $this->triabc;
//   }  else {
//   $this->triId = $this->shopId . $this->triacb;
//   }
}
```

I call it in my services.yaml:

```
App\EventListener\NewOrganised:
    tags:
        -
            name: 'doctrine.event_listener'
            priority: 500
            connection: 'default'
```

I am not sure if I should do as I did in my Entity and call an entityManagerInterface there to get value of the rows wanted or in my EventListener:

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    $entityRef = $args->getObject();
 
    // if this listener only applies to certain entity types,
    // add some code to check the entity type as early as possible
    if (!$entity instanceof ProductsInfoOrganised) {
        return;
    }
 
    if (!$entityRef instanceof ProductsInfoOrganisation) {
        return;
    }
    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
    // ... do something with the Product entity
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should share the models code instead of an Excel sheet screenshot which in my opinion is just confusing.

Comment: I don't have models. I can share entities code but as it was generic, i didn't think it was worth it and as I am French, rows were in French, I translated row names for clarification in Excel

Comment: Entity source code (showing relations) is best. If you can access the entity then you can access the related entity and use the entity manager to persist changes.

Comment: Quick answer, yes you can access data from another entity. If entity A have a ManyToOne relation with entity B, you can do `$a->getB()->getValue()`, doctrine will do the query to retrieve (and hydrade) entity B from database for you. Please provider your entity classes :)